# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

In my Project I am having a WebService for generating a list, when I run the WebService I get the `NullReference Exception` in the `c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx`.

Could anybody point me what is the problem in my code?

The Code I tried is:

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Services;
  using System.Data.SqlClient;
  using System.Data;
  using SubSonic;

  [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
  [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
  [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
  [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class AutoComplete : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
public AutoComplete()
{
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

 public string[] Getlist(string keywordstartswith)
   {
    IList<string> output = new List<string>();
    Dictionary<string, string> mydict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    string QueryString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings   ["IUMSNXG"].ToString();
    IDataReader obj_result = SearchApp.DBCon.LRS_SP_CBFM_Sel(keywordstartswith).GetReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(obj_result);
    if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
         while (obj_result.Read())
         {
            output.Add(string.Format("{0}~{1}", obj_result["AnimalCode"].ToString().TrimEnd(), obj_result["pk_animalid"].ToString().TrimEnd()));
         } 
    }
    return output.ToArray();
  }
 }
```

The Source Error I am Getting is:

```
Line 1333:
Line 1334:    OperationBinding FindHttpBinding(string verb) {
Line 1335:        foreach (ServiceDescription description in serviceDescriptions) // Getting Error Here
                   {
Line 1336:            foreach (Binding binding in description.Bindings) {
Line 1337:                HttpBinding httpBinding = (HttpBinding)binding.Extensions.Find(typeof(HttpBinding));
```

The Stack Trace is

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.FindHttpBinding(String verb) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx:1335
   ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.get_HttpPostOperationBinding() in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx:526
   ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.get_ShowingHttpPost() in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx:541
   ASP.defaultwsdlhelpgenerator_aspx.__Render__control20(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 \Config\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx:1574
  System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +109
  System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
  System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +31
  System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
  System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
  System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
  System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +208
  System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +8
  System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +29
  System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +27
  System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +100
  System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +25
  System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3060
```

Comment: Where in your code is the error?

Comment: @ Kostas the error is not coming in the Code file I have created, the **Nullreference Exception** is in `DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx`

Comment: @Rajesh But which line?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Then you can tell us which line is breaking.

Comment: @ Soner & Azhar I had tried to put a Break Point in the Code to find out the Occurance point of the Error but during running then Exception is coming even the Breakpoint at first line

Comment: Did you try this in a fresh machine. If not then please try it there.@Rajesh

Comment: is public string[] Getlist(string keywordstartswith) your web method?

Comment: @ Rezoan Yes `public string[] Getlist(string keywordstartswith)` is my WebMethod and I had tried in a differant System but Same Result.

Comment: doesn't it necessary to put [WebMethod] in top of any asp.net webservice's webmethod? if necessary then put [WebMethod] on the top of your web method.@ Rajesh

Comment: @ Rezoan I can't catch your point as I am this is my First Web Service Project if you don't mind kindly explain via coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[WebMethod]** attribute is missing from your WebMethod.
Try to write your web method like,

```
        [WebMethod]
        public string[] Getlist(string keywordstartswith)
        {
            IList<string> output = new List<string>();
            Dictionary<string, string> mydict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string QueryString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IUMSNXG"].ToString();
            IDataReader obj_result = SearchApp.DBCon.LRS_SP_CBFM_Sel(keywordstartswith).GetReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(obj_result);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                while (obj_result.Read())
                {
                    output.Add(string.Format("{0}~{1}", obj_result["AnimalCode"].ToString().TrimEnd(), obj_result["pk_animalid"].ToString().TrimEnd()));
                }
            }
            return output.ToArray();
        }
```

Attaching the **[WebMethod]** attribute to a Public method indicates that you want the method exposed as part of the XML Web service

Comment: I had Edited with the `[WebMethod]` on the top of my Web Method but while Running same Exception Occurs.

Comment: By the way could you please confirm me : just create a brand new asp.net webservice and without doing anything just try to run it and does it run successfully?@ Rajesh

Comment: I had Created a Fresh Web Service with No Code in it and Tried to run it but Same Exception was thrown.

Comment: Then it is not the web service problem. your code is ok. it is your IIS issue. try to unistall your IIS and then install it again. it should work. But i am getting confused why your webservice just not running in different machine. Did you actually test there? it is pretty working in my machine.

Answer (score 3):

The ASP.Net handler that generates the output for get requests to the asmx resource doesn't work if AutoEventWireup is disabled for your web site.  This is unfortunate since disabling that is a performance best practice.  [Enable it in your web.config](http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324151) temporarily, and turn it off when you are done.

(hat tip to [Bryan Allott](http://bryanallott.net/blog/2007/06/defaultwsdlhelpgenerator-gotcha.html))

Answer (score 1):

As a solution you can add <%@ Page autoEventWireup="true" %> to the top of
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx